# Finding number of characters,words and lines in a text file

Tags: c, file, text

Here is the .c file followed by the functions in my .h file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "functions.h"
#define INPUT_FILE "C:/Users/user/Desktop/test.txt"






int main(){
    FILE *text_file;
    int num_characters, num_words, num_lines;


    text_file = fopen(INPUT_FILE,"r");

    if(text_file == NULL){
        printf("!!-------ERROR OPENING FILE------!!\nclosing program....");
        return 0;
    }

    num_characters = read_characters(text_file);
    num_words = read_words(text_file);
    num_lines = read_lines(text_file);

    printf("Number of Characters: %d\nNumber of Words: %d\nNumber of Lines: %d\n",num_characters,num_words,num_lines);


    return 0;
}


#include <stdio.h>
#include "functions.h"
#define INPUT_FILE "C:/Users/Lott-kerby/Desktop/test.txt"





#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H_
#define FUNCTIONS_H_
#include <stdio.h>


int read_characters(FILE *text_file){
    int i;
    int char_count = 0;
    while((i = fgetc(text_file)) !=EOF)
        char_count++;


    return char_count;
}


int read_words(FILE *text_file){
    char j;
    int word_count = 0;
    while((j = fgetc(text_file)) != EOF){
        if(j == ' ')
            word_count++;
    }
    return word_count;
}

int read_lines(FILE *text_file){
    char k;
    int line_count = 0;
    while((k = fgetc(text_file)) != EOF){
        if(k == '\n')
            line_count++;
    }
    return line_count;
}
```

The goal is to find the number of characters words and lines in the text file. I get the correct number of characters when i run but I get the incorrect number of words and lines. The text file I am using is as follows:

```
word
word
word
```

with this .txt my program out put is:
Number of characers:14
NUmber of words: 0
Number of Lines: 0

any help would be greatly appreciated. The "words" are on their own line each in my text file.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you should only have the declarations of functions in functions.h, not the functions themselves. They should be in functions.c.

Comment: Since i, j and k is doing the same job and are in different functions, you can use the same name in all 3 functions. Is there a specific reason, why you don't do the 3 countings in one function?

Comment: @MikkelChristiansen I am doing it this way because i can obtain extra points for the encapsulation

Comment: That is a good reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you count the nunmber of words by counting the number of spaces because you assume there is a space between every word. but in your example input file there are no spaces.

So you may want to add a check for space OR new line.

Also you may want to return word_count+1 and line_count+1 because a single line without a newline should return 1. And the same is true for a single word with no space

**EDIT**: oouuhh and now I see that you read the file multiple times without resetting the file pointer so fgetc will always instantly return EOF in read_words() and read_lines() ... reset it using

```
rewind ( text_file );
```

Comment: my edit is important, so make sure you notice it :-) feel free to ask if it is still not working

Comment: should i call this after every function call? In my .c file?

Comment: I would say in the functions before the while loops. Btw. I browser your questions so far. You should really consider accepting/upvoting those questions that helped you...

Comment: i do but i have only 14 reputation so my upvotes dont show

Comment: you have to check the green check arrow below the vote counter of the answer to accept it. do this with all your questions that have been answered and it will gain you a lot of repution just by accepting it.